# Using VMDK image on VirtualBox: disable tty

Tags: boot, virtualbox, tty

I'm booting VMDK images on VirtualBox and adding a cloud-init config, I have a nice way to produce blueprinted VMs on Linux. However, they depend on having a TTY defined and that makes that I can't finish the boot process on a Windows VirtualBox.

Is there any way to configure the VM in such a way that it doesn't require the TTY after the first boot?

Thanks & stay safe and healty, /Pedro A.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I have been trying with the different releases in http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com and VirtualBox 6.0. And I have come up with a way of making this work, Anyhow, thanks a ton